# what does @ mean when used in preg_match?

Tags: php

This is from a class there is a @ sign in preg_match what does it mean or its purpose? Does it mean a space?

```
if (preg_match("@Property Information </td>@",simplexml_import_dom($cols->item(0))->asXML(),$ok))
{
     $table_name = 'Property Information';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, it is being used as a [pattern delimiter](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters). As that manual page says,

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~).

Answer (score 1):

It is just a delimiter. It can be any other pair of character. The following are all the same

```
"@Property Information </td>@"
"+Property Information </td>+"
"|Property Information </td>|"
"#Property Information </td>#"
"[Property Information </td>]"
...
```

The purpose of the delimiter to separate regex pattern with modifier, e.g. if you need case-insensitive match you'll put an `i` after the delimiter, e.g.

```
"@Property Information </td>@i"
"+Property Information </td>+i"
"|Property Information </td>|i"
"#Property Information </td>#i"
"[Property Information </td>]i"
...
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php for detail.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any character - when appearing at the first position - can be used as a PCRE delimiter. In this case it's the `@` (another common one would be `/` but when dealing with closing tags that one is not really good as you'd have to escape every `/` in the text
)

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php for details.

---

However, you shouldn't use a Regex for this check at all - you are just testing if a plain string is in another string. Here's a proper solution:

```
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($cols->item(0))->asXML()
if(strpos($xml, 'Property Information </td>') !== false) { ... }
```

Actually, using string operators when dealing with html/xml is not really nice but if you are just doing simple "contains" checks it's usually the easiest way.

Comment: thanks, since those @'s are being used as an alternative to the / how is it looking for the text and the </td> tag when the first param is a regex pattern by default

Comment: Since it's a plain string without any special characters no regex features are used at all - and because of this, see the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

every regular expression must start and end with the same character. the author of the given regular expression has chosen to start and end the regular expression with an `@` sign.